# Where is the best place to call the .tolist(); inside my controller classes or inside my model repository classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following action method, inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
public JsonResult LoadZoneByDataCenter(string id)
        {
            var zonelist = repository.getrealtedzone(Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToList();
//code goes here
```

Which calls the following model repository method:-

```
 public IQueryable<Zone> getrealtedzone(int? dcid) {

         return   tms.Zones.Where(a=> a.DataCenterID == dcid || dcid == null);
        }
```

Currently I am calling the .tolist() which will interpret the Database from my action method, but my question is where is the best place to call the .tolist() inside the controller or inside the model classes and why ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to not call `.ToList()` in your repository but rather in your controllers. This way you could perform and combine multiple complex queries from the repositories into a single database call. And once you have the entire mix of data your view will require, call `.ToList()` to execute the SQL query. Otherwise, for things that could be handled by SQL JOINs you will be making multiple queries.